# Bash script output JSON variable to file

Tags: json, linux, bash

I am using twurl in Ubuntu's command line to connect to the Twitter Streaming API, and parse the resulting JSON with [this processor](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/). I have the following command, which returns the text of tweets sent from London:

```
twurl -t -d locations=-5.67,50.06,1.76,58.62 language=en -H stream.twitter.com /1.1/statuses/filter.json | jq '.text'
```

This works great, but I'm struggling to output the result to a file called london.txt. I have tried the following, but still no luck:

```
twurl -t -d locations=-5.67,50.06,1.76,58.62 language=en -H stream.twitter.com /1.1/statuses/filter.json | jq '.text' > london.txt
```

As I'm fairly new to Bash scripting, I'm sure I've misunderstood the proper use of '>' and '>>', so if anyone could point me in the right direction that'd be awesome!

Comment: `command > file` truncates the file and redirects the output of command to this file. The `>>` does the same, but it appends instead of truncating. **Remove the redirection part, and see what's being printed**. The result is what you should see in your file.

Comment: Thank you, I understand that much. My problem is that this command doesn't output anything at all to the file,

Comment: What are you getting in `london.txt` when you run that command? Because you should get whatever you got printed to the terminal when you ran it without the redirection.

Comment: Nothing at all! If I run it without the `> london.txt` I get what I'm expecting. The jq '.text' returns just the text of the tweet to the terminal, but I can't get anything to save to a file...

Comment: It would be nice if we could test this ourselves without needing to set up a Twitter account. Could you, perhaps, copy down a sample of the returned value to somewhere publicly available (ideally, a pastebin that allows raw access, so instead of `twurl ... | jq` we could run `curl ... | jq` to reproduce your result)?

Comment: (Suffice to say that what you're reporting is not at all normal behavior... and while it's _possible_ for a program such as `jq` to change its behavior based on whether or not its output is to a TTY, I use it quite frequently, and have never seen anything like what you're describing).

Answer (score 0):

```
twurl -t -d locations=-5.67,50.06,1.76,58.62 language=en -H stream.twitter.com /1.1/statuses/filter.json | jq '.text' > london.txt
```

It will replace on each new line pasting on it. But if you use `>>` it will append the next write operation to end of file. So try the following rather above example, I'm certain it will work.

```
twurl -t -d locations=-5.67,50.06,1.76,58.62 language=en -H stream.twitter.com /1.1/statuses/filter.json | jq '.text' >> london.txt
```

Also you can use `tee` command to check what is printing along side the redirection

```
twurl -t -d locations=-5.67,50.06,1.76,58.62 language=en -H stream.twitter.com /1.1/statuses/filter.json | jq '.text'| tee london.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, exactly the same problem. Nothing outputs at all!

Comment: Can you please check the last one @DanB

Comment: Same result. Could it be something to do with the connection needing to be closed in a specific way?

Comment: Yeah may be that is the problem @DanB but I don't actually have any knowledge in connection oriented matter in this case, So I don't think I would help much about it. And sorry to take you precious time, just wanted to help you.